# Не добавляются данные в БД при том, не выбрасывает ошибок

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

Я в тупике. Пытаюсь создать простое JPA приложение. По туториулу сделал сущность и persistance.xml. Также для проверки скопировал main.java. Все работает, данные в базу добавляются. Из другого примера, пытаюсь добавить EJB, компилирую - ошибок IDE не выдает, при компиляции эксепшенов нет, в логах сервера все красиво, а данные в базу не добавляются. Я понимаю, что я могу использовать решение, как в main.java, но хочется EJB и @PersistenceContext. Что я упускаю?

Todo.java

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Todo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String summary;
    private String description;

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Todo [summary=" + summary + ", description=" + description
                + "]";
    }

}
```

ModelTodo.java

```
package model;

import entity.Todo;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class ModelTodo {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "todos")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void saveSummary(Todo todo){
        entityManager.persist(todo);
    }
}
```

index.java

```
...
    @EJB
    ModelTodo modelTodo;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Todo todo = new Todo();
        todo.setSummary("Porsche");
        todo.setDescription("911");

        modelTodo.saveSummary(todo);
    }
}
...
```

Main.java (при запуске этого кода - данные в таблицу добавляются)

```
public class Main {
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "todos";
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        // read the existing entries and write to console
        Query q = em.createQuery("select t from Todo t");
        List<Todo> todoList = q.getResultList();
        for (Todo todo : todoList) {
            System.out.println(todo);
        }
        System.out.println("Size: " + todoList.size());

        // create new todo
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Todo todo = new Todo();
        todo.setSummary("Lincoln");
        todo.setDescription("This is a test");
        em.persist(todo);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что вы не написали код, который добавляет ежб в бд.

Comment: @RomanC разве не написал? В сервлете я сетую название в переменную
` todo.setSummary("Porsche");
        todo.setDescription("911");

        modelTodo.saveSummary(todo); `
А в ModelTodo я закидываю значение переменной в БД
`    public void saveSummary(Todo todo){
         entityManager.persist(todo);
     } `

Comment: Киньте ссылку на туториал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что PersistenceContext работает только при типе транзакции JTA (Указывается в Persistance.xml), а у меня тип RESOURCE_LOCAL - при таком подключении к БД, нужно самому управлять транзакцией, использовать EntityManagerFactory и аннотация другая PersistanceUnit. Когда я добавил этот код на сервере WebSphere все заработало. К слову на WebLogic так и не пашет, но хотя бы ошибки стал выдавать